# How to access certain database tables in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails as a JSON API. My database has the following structure: the City model has_many Users, which in turn has_many Businesses.

When I send a GET request to businesses#index, I want Rails to return all the businesses in a given city, not just for a given user. What's the best way to do this?

I've already tried the given code below as a first pass, which is returning an internal server error (500).

```
def index
    @city = City.find(params[:city_id])

    @users = @city.users
    @businesses = @users.businesses

    render json: @businesses
end
```

Comment: Post your models too. May be the issue is there

Comment: What is the exact error message including the stack trace (find it in the log file)?

Comment: I think the problem is that you cannot just call `@users.businesses`, you would need to call `@users.map(&:businesses)`. The reason is that `businesses` relation is for a single user, while you call this method on `@users` which represents a list

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? 
Because of the `@user` is an array. so the error will occuring.

```js
# city.rb
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end

#user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
  has_many :businesses
end

#business.rb

class Business < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end


# your controller

def get_business
  @city = City.find(params[:id])
  @business = @city.users.includes(:business)
  render json: @business
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new relationship to your City model:
`has_many businesses, through: users`

Then when you have a specific city you can get all businesses:
`@city.businesses`

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try starting with the Business model to make the query.

```
Business.joins(user: :city).where(cities: { id: params[:city_id] })
```

`joins` uses the association names

`where` uses the table names